# My PyTorch GAN is changing from producing random noise to darkness with no convergence. Why is this?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

My code is very basic, just following the first lab from DeepLearning.ai's GAN specialization. However, my code does not have the same output, what is the reason for this. Sorry if this is just a silly mistake, this is my first experience with GANs. I begin by creating the Generator and Discriminator classes, my random noise function, and creating my models. I then run the training loop, but after 3 epochs, all of the outputs from the GAN are black.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

torch.manual_seed(0)

def show_tensor_images(image_tensor,num_images=25,size=(1,28,28)):
    image_unflat=image_tensor.detach().cpu().view(-1,*size)
    image_grid=make_grid(image_unflat[:num_images],nrow=5)
    plt.imshow(image_grid.permute(1,2,0).squeeze())
    plt.show()

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,z_dim):
        super(Generator,self).__init__()
        self.linear1=nn.Linear(z_dim,128)
        self.bn1=nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.linear2=nn.Linear(128,256)
        self.bn2=nn.BatchNorm1d(256)
        self.linear3=nn.Linear(256,512)
        self.bn3=nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
        self.linear4=nn.Linear(512,1024)
        self.bn4=nn.BatchNorm1d(1024)
        self.linear5=nn.Linear(1024,784)
        self.relu=nn.ReLU(True)
        self.sigmoid=nn.Sigmoid()
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.linear1(x)
        x=self.bn1(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear2(x)
        x=self.bn2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear3(x)
        x=self.bn3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear4(x)
        x=self.bn4(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear5(x)
        x=self.sigmoid(x)
        return(x)

def get_noise(n_samples,z_dim,device='cpu'):
    return torch.randn(n_samples,z_dim,device=device)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator,self).__init__()
        self.linear1=nn.Linear(784,512)
        self.linear2=nn.Linear(512,256)
        self.linear3=nn.Linear(256,128)
        self.linear4=nn.Linear(128,1)
        self.relu=nn.LeakyReLU(0.2,True)
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.linear1(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.linear4(x)
        return(x)

criterion=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
epochs=200
z_dim=64
display_step=500
batch_size=128
lr=0.00001
device='cuda'

dataloader=DataLoader(MNIST('.',download=True,transform=transforms.ToTensor()),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

gen=Generator(z_dim).to(device)
gen_opt=torch.optim.Adam(gen.parameters(),lr=lr)
disc=Discriminator().to(device)
disc_opt=torch.optim.Adam(disc.parameters(),lr=lr)

def get_disc_loss(gen,disc,criterion,real,num_images,z_dim,device):
    noise=get_noise(num_images,z_dim,device=device)
    gen_out=gen(noise)
    disc_fake_out=disc(gen_out.detach())
    fake_loss=criterion(disc_fake_out,torch.zeros_like(disc_fake_out))
    disc_real_out=disc(real)
    real_loss=criterion(disc_real_out,torch.zeros_like(disc_real_out))
    disc_loss=(fake_loss+real_loss)/2
    return(disc_loss)

def get_gen_loss(gen,disc,criterion,num_images,z_dim,device):
    noise=get_noise(num_images,z_dim,device=device)
    gen_out=gen(noise)
    disc_out=disc(gen_out)
    loss=criterion(disc_out,torch.ones_like(disc_out))
    return loss

cur_step=0
mean_generator_loss=0
mean_discriminator_loss=0
gen_loss=False
error=False
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for x,_ in tqdm(dataloader):
        cur_batch_size=len(x)
        x=x.view(cur_batch_size,-1).to(device)

        disc_opt.zero_grad()
        disc_loss=get_disc_loss(gen,disc,criterion,x,cur_batch_size,z_dim,device)
        disc_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        disc_opt.step()

        gen_opt.zero_grad()
        gen_loss=get_gen_loss(gen,disc,criterion,cur_batch_size,z_dim,device)
        gen_loss.backward()
        gen_opt.step()

        mean_discriminator_loss+=disc_loss.item()/display_step
        mean_generator_loss+=gen_loss.item()/display_step

        if cur_step%display_step==0 and cur_batch_size>0:
            print(f"Step {cur_step}: Generator loss: {mean_generator_loss}, discriminator loss: {mean_discriminator_loss}")
            fake_noise = get_noise(cur_batch_size, z_dim, device=device)
            fake = gen(fake_noise)
            show_tensor_images(fake)
            show_tensor_images(x)
            mean_generator_loss = 0
            mean_discriminator_loss = 0
        cur_step += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your discriminator loss is wrong. The labels for the real images should be `1` instead of `0`.

Updated code:

```py
def get_disc_loss(gen,disc,criterion,real,num_images,z_dim,device):
    noise=get_noise(num_images,z_dim,device=device)
    gen_out=gen(noise)
    disc_fake_out=disc(gen_out.detach())
    fake_loss=criterion(disc_fake_out,torch.zeros_like(disc_fake_out))
    disc_real_out=disc(real)
    real_loss=criterion(disc_real_out,torch.ones_like(disc_real_out))
    disc_loss=(fake_loss+real_loss)/2
    return(disc_loss)
```

The output image looks pretty good to me:
[image]

Comment: Hi can u explain to me why generator is trained after the discriminator , and also is the discriminator trained with the image generated by the the generator at each epoch ?